# Binary Search a List of custom data types to match just one field

Tags: c#, list, search

I have a List:

```
List<Student> allStudents = new List<Student>();
```

that contains over 94,000 Student objects, where Student is defined as:

```
public class Student
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    public String Surname { get; set; }
    public String Other_Names { get; set; }
    public String DOB { get; set; }
    // remaining fields omitted
}
```

and sorted by Surname.

After grabbing a Student object from another source, I want to binary search the List allStudents to find a match based ONLY on the Surname property. For example, if an existing record in the List allStudents is:

```
Student(8139241, "Flintstone", "Fred", "12/1/1967")
```

and I search for the item:

```
Student(7294311, "Flintstone", "Wilma", "14/6/1969")
```

the binary search should be a success.

The List.BinarySearch(T, IComparer) overload appears to be a possibility, but is it a viable solution? Or is there a better strategy? I will be dealing a lot of records and searches, so O(n) search functions will not be viable.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: I've decided to replace my List with a MultiDictionary from the Wintellect PowerCollections library. This MultiDictionary can accept duplicate keys.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

List.BinarySearch is a good solution and works like you would expect.  Here's a link that shows a [solution similar](https://web.archive.org/web/20201128225015/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/110602-1.2.aspx) to what you'll need for the IComparer.  Their example doesn't use the Generic IComparer, though.

```
public class CompareCustomDataType : IComparer<Student> {

  public int Compare(Student x, Student y)
  {
    if (x == y)    return 0;
    if (x == null) return -1;
    if (y == null) return 1;

    return String.Compare(x.Surname, y.Surname);
  }
...
}
```

Comment: The [link](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/110602-1.2.aspx) is dead. Also for a more flexible string comparison you could use the [`StringComparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer) class: `return StringComparer.Ordinal.Compare(x.Surname, y.Surname);`

Answer (score 2):

Define the `IComparable<T>` interface for your `Student` class. Then all the sort and comparison methods of your list, including `BinarySearch()` will you use this one automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It has the following  limitation

1. If the List contains more than one element with the same value, the method returns only one of the occurrences, and it might return any one of the occurrences, not necessarily the first one.
2. The List must already be sorted according to the comparer implementation; otherwise, the result is incorrect.

> I would suggest you to use Linq to find the Matching Data from your list.

```
  var data = students.where(o => o.SurName='xxxxx');
```

**> You can also use the Find or FindAll methods from the List object using predicates.**

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input. @Amit is there an advantage to using Linq? I know that Find and FindAll are linear searches; is a Linq query better amortized?

Comment: i am not an expert at linq;Linq use Linear Search. Linq is a structured programming technique which make the code more readable and understandable. Like if you see the statement is quite obvious the line of code is trying to find all the items in the list which matches the Surname field.

Answer (score 0):

With that many entries you would probably be better off using a `Dictionary<string, Student>` lookup, which would be amortized O(1). Although there could probably be multiple Students with the same surname, so it would have be something like `Dictionary<string, List<Student>>`

Also as Amit pointed out, using a binary search when there are duplicate items can be tricky, because you don't know which index you will get in the series of duplicates. You would have to search to the left and right of the returned index to see if any other matching surnames exist.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The Dictionary idea seems very attractive due to O(1) amortization but the closest thing I've ever used are Perl hashes, so I'm trying to get my head around it. To be exact, I need to find matches between my List<Student> and a data table Graduates(Surname, Other_Names, ..., ...,). The only two fields in common are Surname and Other_Names, so obviously they're the only fields to match on.

Comment: But since a Dictionary can only have one key per pair, and I need to match two Strings (Surname and Other_Names), I need to think about how to structure the Dictionary so that it can be matched against the List<Student>. Ugh, details...

Comment: Maybe I can define a class Name(Surname, Other_Names) and then make a Dictionary(<Name, Student>). But then if there are several people with the same Name (e.g. John Smith from California and John Smith from Idaho), the keys would no longer be unique, which is bad. Then maybe defining the Name class as Name(Surname, Other_Names, UniqueID) would work. Hmm........

Comment: Or maybe I should totally get rid of the List and go with a more easily-accessed data structure like a Dictionary. Because as long as I have all my Students in a List<Student>, I will still need to traverse that List to merge the Student that I grab from another source, regardless of any other optimizations. Now I need to think how to replace my List with a Dictionary.