# Problem on a struct exercise

Tags: c#

I'm currently learning about structs, so I have the following exercise:
Set a Struct that called "Date" that contains date, including: year, month and day. Also, define a class called Phone that contains a name, number, date of birth and address. You need to create an array that contains objects of type Phone and sort them by name, number, and date.
Alright, so this is the code:

```
  struct Date
{
    int year, month, day;
    public Date(int year, int month, int day)
    {
        this.year = year;
        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
    }
    public int Year
    {
        get { return year; }
        set {year = value; }
    }
    public int Month
    {
        get { return month; }
        set { month = value; }
    }
    public int Day
    {
        get { return day; }
        set { day = value; }
    }
}
    class Phone
{
    string number;
    string adress; 
    string name;
    Date birthday = new Date(); 
    public Phone(string number,Date birthday, string adress, string name)
    {
        this.number = number;
        this.birthday = birthday;
        this.adress = adress;
        this.name = name;
    }

}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Phone[] p = new Phone[3];
        p[0] = new Phone(1072548,
     }
}
```

I'm having no error but the problem is that I don't know how to get the birthday from the "Date" struct, and that's why I stopped putting in the information.
Thanks.

Comment: why create date with Class ? and use struct ?

Comment: Why would you model a phone that has a birthday property? Is it the birthday of the phone? What an odd thing to want to keep track of.

Comment: lol, I didn't understand you guys, are you saying that I've done something wrong or the question is just stupid?

Comment: You should consider making the struct immutable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Struct exercise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496123/struct-exercise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p[0] = new Phone(1072548,
   new Date (1999, 12, 31),
   "Central Park, NY", "Sam Party")
```

Maybe add this to your Date struct:

```
public DateTime ToDateTime ()
{
   return new DateTime (Year, Month, Day);
}
```

Then, you can sort your array like this:

```
array.OrderBy (p => p.BirthDate.ToDateTime ());
```

Comment: Thank you!! Another thing, do I sort the array using the binary search or..?

Comment: @Rich, take a look at my answer to this question.  It will probably help, but you may need the non-Generic option described in the web page I mentioned. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488201/binary-search-a-list-of-custom-data-types-to-match-just-one-field/6488234#6488234

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Date
{
    Date()
    {
       //code
    }
}

class Phone
{
    Phone(string "someParametr")
    {
      //code
    }
}
```

you need two Contractor.